# Drupal 7: How to only allow child levels of taxonomy item to be chosen as category when adding content

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

I have a content type which has a category field based on taxonomy.  but I want editors to only be able to choose the child categories for each content piece, not the parent categories.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

i have code similar to this look if might help you in some kind ... it gets childs and parents in an array if you are planning to make it by using custom module ...

```
 $tree_type =  taxonomy_get_tree(3);
    $childs["selected"]="All";

    foreach($tree_type as $key =>$value) {
                $temp_ = taxonomy_term_load($value->parents[0]);           //IF parent is set already
            if($value->parents[0]==0) {                             //if no any parent taxonomy
                    if(is_object($temp_)==TRUE) {                 //CHECK IF SINGLE iTEM PARENT
                    if(isset($childs[$temp_->name])) {           //if array key is already set 
                            if(is_array($key)!=FALSE) {         //if value is not an array
                    $childs[$temp_->name][$tree_type[$key]->tid]=array($key=>$value->name);  // set the parent child array
                            }
                    }else {
                            if(is_array($key)!=FALSE) {    //if value is not an array
                    $childs[$temp_->name][$tree_type[$key]->tid]=array($key=>$value->name);  // set the parent child array
                            }
                        }
                    }else
                    {
                        $childs[$value->name]=array();
                        $childs[$value->name][$tree_type[$key]->tid]="-".$value->name;
                        //drupal_set_message("-------<pre>".$value->name."</pre>-------");
                        //drupal_set_message("<pre>".print_r($childs,true)."</pre>");
                        }
                }else {
        $childs[$temp_->name][$tree_type[$key]->tid]=$value->name;          //$childs[$temp_->tid]=$temp_->name;
                }
        }
```